# I have a question. I'd like to wait for certain conditions. By selenium

Tags: selenium

When I crawl using selenium, If the number of open Chrome browser windows is more than 5, I want to wait the program and if the number of windows is less than 5, I want to design the program to continue crawling again.
But I can't design this myself with my poor skills.
Plese Help me, My bro..

```
def run_code():
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    import time

    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True) 
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"]) 

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

    driver.get("https://goodday.com/bbs/")
    elements = driver.find_elements('xpath', '//*[@id="list-body"]/li/div[1]/a')[:-1]

    for link in elements:
        link = link.get_attribute("href")
        driver.execute_script('window.open("/");')  

        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1]) 
        driver.get(link)
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        time.sleep(1)

        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])  
        time.sleep(2)

        opened_window = len(driver.window_handles)
        print(f"opened_window length : {opened_window} opened.")


if __name__=="__main__":
    run_code()
```

Comment: And what's the problem with the given code? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Before Switching the new window, you can check the no of open browser window and if count more than 5 then wait for that.

```
noOfOpenWindows=len(driver.window_handles)
if noOfOpenWindows <=5:
   continue
else:
   time.sleep(30) # provide time as you like
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I already knew this. 
What I want is to continue to detect the number of windows in real time.
The code you wrote down is not suitable because it determines the condition only once and moves on right away.